# A famous Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know there is a famous inequality between $\Sigma_{i<j}^{n} x_{i}x_{j}$ and $x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}$ but I don't remember what exactly it is . For example in the case $n=2$ we have:

$x_{1}+x_{2}\ge 2(x_{1}x_{2})^{1/2}$.

I was wondering if anybody could help with that.

Comment: Are you talking about the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [The inequality of arithmetic and geometric means?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Now I remember. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If you are sufficiently happy with my answer, please accept the answer to clear it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i\neq j}2x_i x_j= (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,A_n\,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T \tag{1}$$
where the entries of $A_n$ equal one unless they are diagonal entries: in such a case they equal zero. $A_n+I_n$ is a rank-$1$ matrix with eigenvalues $n,0,\ldots,0$. It follows that the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are $n-1,-1,\ldots,-1$ and:
$$ \left|f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\right|\leq (n-1)(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2).\tag{2} $$
By $(2)$, we have:

> $$ \left|\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_i x_j\right|\leq \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\tag{3} $$

and equality holds iff $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$.
On the other hand, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^2\leq n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\tag{4}$$
hence:

> $$ 2\cdot\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\!\!x_i x_j = (x_1+\ldots+x_n)^2 - (x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^2.\tag{5} $$